# DRYing up my Service files for Systemd

Tags: systemd

Right now I have systemd service files with 20+ environment variables in them, expressed as `Environment=` This is a lot of duplication that I would like to git rid of since I have systemd files for **celery**, **gunicorn**, and **celerybeat**.

I'd like to have one file that is `included` into each of the unit files and it appears one way to do this is like this:

> The correct way to do this is to create a directory named after the unit file with .d appended on the end. So for a unit called example.service, a subdirectory called example.service.d could be created. Within this directory a file ending with .conf can be used to override or extend the attributes of the system’s unit file.

But that still has me trapped in the name of the file matching the service name.  My first thought was to symlink all of the services to the same folder so that `gunicorn.d` is a link to `celery.d` is a link to `celerybeat.d`. That way every service would have the same file and the only extra setup would be to create the links.

So, should I do that with Symlinks at the directory level or hard links at the file level under those directories.

OR am I going about this completely wrong and there is some super simple method to deal with this that I just haven't found.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `EnvironmentFile=`. That's one line per service file.

Also, convert your services to *template* units which can be started with different instances, e.g. having a `gunicorn@.service` unit would allow you to start both `gunicorn@app1.service` and `gunicorn@app2.service`, both sharing most of the same parameters – except for what's added or overridden through each instance's `gunicorn@appX.service.d/` directory. The instances can be individually controlled, enabled, etc.

Units can use `%i` to reference their instance, e.g. `EnvironmentFile=/etc/webapps/%i.env` would expand to "app1.env".

(Actually you're not required to have the template unit at all; you could do it the other way around, by having several *real* `gunicorn@appX.service` units, and then overriding certain common parameters through the common `gunicorn@.service.d/`.)

You can indeed symlink files inside `.d/` directories – I would probably recommend doing that at file level, as this would retain the possibility of adding a *second* config file for that one weird service that needs special configuration. (Whereas if you symlink whole `.d/` directories, then all of them *must* have the same content, no way around it.)

Recent systemd versions support a second mechanism very similar to instances, but implicitly using `-` as hierarchy separator. If you have a unit named `foo-bar-baz.service`, then configuration will also be loaded from `foo-bar-.service.d/` and `foo-.service.d/`. This is mostly useful for other unit types like .slice, but can be used for services too. (Similarly to `%i`, the unit can reference the *last* dash-separated part of its name using `%j`.)

---

As a historical note, systemd *used to have* an `.include /path/to/stuff` keyword (predating the existence of `.d` directories) but this was removed in v246.

Comment: I used the EnvironmentFile= options.  Not quite to the point of needing templated units yet since I only have 1 of each, but when I do, I'll convert them to template units.